How to do multipart/mixed requests?
I'm tinkering with a website which is part of what SAP provides companies to do their work time accounting.
I found out that what I'm planning to do is actually a post request, and here is what I took from the Chrome developer console Request payload field. I recorded this when I clicked on the button that I wanted to replicate. It actually creates three(3) requests that look similar to the one below, but as far as I see don't contain relevant information.
 --batch_5932-e086-aabb
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_f03e-c18c-f82d

--changeset_f03e-c18c-f82d
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST TimeEventSet?sap-client=100 HTTP/1.1
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: de
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
x-csrf-token: <some-token>==
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 153

{"EmployeeID":"<some-number>","EventDate":"2024-04-19T00:00:00","EventTime":"PT15H15M29S","TimeType":"<some-code>","TimezoneOffset":"<some-offset>","ApproverPernr":"<some-number>"}
--changeset_f03e-c18c-f82d--

--batch_5932-e086-aabb--

There is a couple of examples on the net that show how to do file transfers with mutlipart requests. Here is what I tried on a different occasion but gives me some random server error, that the syntax is wrong. That was created by recording a har file in chrome and using the python package har2requests
r = session.post(
    "<some-url>",
    params={"sap-client": "100"},
    data='\r\n--batch_9003-5d2c-29c4\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_34fb-a3ca-3327\r\n\r\n--changeset_34fb-a3ca-3327\r\nContent-Type: application/http\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\nPOST TimeEventSet?sap-client=100 HTTP/1.1\r\nsap-contextid-accept: header\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nAccept-Language: de\r\nDataServiceVersion: 2.0\r\nMaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0\r\nx-csrf-token: <some-token>==Content-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 152\r\n\r\n{"EmployeeID":"<some-number>","EventDate":"2024-04-19T00:00:00","EventTime":"PT17H10M6S","TimeType":"<some-code>","TimezoneOffset":"<some-offset>","ApproverPernr":"<some-number"}\r\n--changeset_34fb-a3ca-3327--\r\n\r\n--batch_9003-5d2c-29c4--\r\n'
)

Any idea how to solve this? I'm aware that the csrf token is hardcoded as well, that is something I need to takle later on too.

--changeset_f03e-c18c-f82d would be the boundary for the multipart request - but what is the "outer" --batch_5932-e086-aabb supposed to be, that looks like a boundary as well? Some sort of HTTP batch request format, presumably. So I would expect that you need to send this request with a Content-Type header that specifies the outer boundary (and whatever the correct Mime Type for this format is supposed to be in the first place.)

You do not have to bother yourself with the multipart related header definitions. The requests module handles this for you.
Below is an example for sending a file and a JSON payload as a multipart with a POST request:
import json
import requests

data = {}
data["json_data1"] = data1_value
data["json_data2"] = data2_value

files = {
    "file": (myfilepath, open(myfilepath, "rb"), "application/octet-stream"),
    "data": ("data", json.dumps(data), "application/json")
}

rsp = requests.post(url, files=files)

rsp_data = json.loads(rsp.content)

